# Probability of more than three normal distributions

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, bayesian

Let $x_i∼N(u_i,\sigma^2_i)$. For two normal distribution, I know that $P(x_1>x_2|u_1,u_2) =  {\displaystyle \Phi }(\frac{u_1-u_2}{\sqrt{\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2}})$. But for more than two distributions, e.g. swimming, only 1 winner out of $n$ players, how to find $P(x_1>x_2,...,x_n)$ if the order of non-winners doesn't matter?

Comment: How can possibly negative $\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2$ appears under the square root?

Comment: Sorry, just fixed it

Comment: Look at the @antkam's comment to the question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3520600/